# Java/Libgdx auto tile

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, libgdx, tiles

im currently developing a little game and because i only got some blocks as walls, i really wanna implement auto tiling. But how to do that ? I havent found any tutorials for it, just one for gamemaker, but that dont work on java :/

I already tried to find the neighbour of a block, than change the style of it, but i think i need to also look for the corner neighbours ? Is that right ?

Does anyone got an idea how to implement such a mechanic ? :)

-------------EDIT--------------

So, ill looked at the wiki and some tutorials of Ze Rubeus, thought it would be solved but theres one problem left :

[image: Wall problem]

It works, when one block touches another, but soon as there's a block of four blocks, it wont work anymore. Normaly, when a block is surrounded by a left neighbour, a right one and one under, also got a corner with the right and left bottom, than it should draw an other image, you can see it in the left and right part.By the way, the value 2 is a wall. Here's what i did :

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------
                    //--------------------Checking for all sides------------------------
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------

                    // got an under neighbour
                    directions[2] = copyOfMap[((int) y)-1][(int) x] == 2; 

                    // got an upper neighbour
                    directions[0] = copyOfMap[((int) y)+1][(int) x] == 2;

                    // got an left neighbour
                    directions[1] = copyOfMap[((int) y)][(int) x-1] == 2;

                    // got an right neighbour
                    directions[3] = copyOfMap[((int) y)][(int) x+1] == 2;

                    //------------------------------------------------------------------
                    //--------------------Checking for corners--------------------------
                    //------------------------------------------------------------------


                    corners[0] = copyOfMap[y-1][x+1] == 2 ;

                    corners[2] = copyOfMap[y-1][x-1] == 2;

                    corners[3] = copyOfMap[y+1][x-1] == 2;

                    corners[1] = copyOfMap[y+1][x+1] == 2;





                    // Right
                    if(directions[3]){

                        if(directions[2]){

                            if(directions[1] && corners[1] && corners[3]){

                                region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                                region.setRegion(32, 0, 32, 32);

                                wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);


                            }
                            else{
                                region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                                region.setRegion(0, 0, 32, 32);

                                wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);
                            }

                        }
                        else if(directions[0]){

                            region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                            region.setRegion(0, 64, 32, 32);

                            wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);

                        }
                        else{

                            region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                            region.setRegion(32, 0, 32, 32);

                            wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);

                        }
                    }





                    // Left
                    else if(directions[1]){

                        if(directions[2]){

                            if(directions[3] && corners[1] && corners[3]){

                                region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                                region.setRegion(32, 0, 32, 32);

                                wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);


                            }   
                            else{
                                region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                                region.setRegion(128, 0, 32, 32);

                                wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);
                            }   

                        }
                        else if(directions[0]){

                            region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                            region.setRegion(128, 32, 32, 32);

                            wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);

                        }
                        else{
                            region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                            region.setRegion(32, 0, 32, 32);

                            wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);
                        }

                    }





                    // Up
                    else if(directions[0]){

                        if(corners[2]){

                            region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                            region.setRegion(0, 32, 32, 32);

                            wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);

                        }
                        else if(corners[3]){

                            region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                            region.setRegion(0, 32, 32, 32);

                            wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);

                        }
                        else{
                            region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                            region.setRegion(0, 32, 32, 32);

                            wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);
                        }

                    }





                    // Down
                    else if(directions[2]){


                        region = game.manager.get("DuengonGainersAtlas/DuengonGainersAtlas",TextureAtlas.class).findRegion("Duengon-WallSet");
                        region.setRegion(0, 32, 32, 32);

                        wallLayer.add(region, (x*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT, (y*100)/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT,100/Box2dVars.UNIT);


                    }
```

Wrote it clearly, so it would be nice if you could look at it :) Just ignore the wallLayer.add and the texture stuff.

Have a great day ^^

Comment: There's a game jam game called Minicraft that does this and it's written in Java. You could look up the source code to get ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Already did it, but Notch did that a little bit too complicated

Comment: Any one got an idea ?

Comment: You say you wrote that clearly but you really didn't. Whenever you method gets longer then 10 lines of code you should ask yourself the question "Can i put certain parts of this in a separate method?". This imight create more lines of code in total but it would be better structured. In your case, and if done properly you would probably get away with two methods `checkDirection(...)` and `checkCorner(...)` and simply loop through them.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply, i am gonna change that as soon as i can :) Yeah i thinks that an better idea, but that wont solve my problem :/ Why there are no tutorials out there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libgdx don't have a feature to auto generate tiles for you, instead you have to implement your owen algorithme to do this kind of stuff.

I suggest that you read [**this**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps) section in the official WIKI, also here is an exemple who provides a [**programmatically generates tilemap**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/bench/TiledMapBench.java), and **[here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-procedurally-generated-dungeon-cave-system--gamedev-10099)** a grate tutoriel on how to Create a Procedurally Generated Dungeon Cave System that you can implement to LIBGDX.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer :) I updated my answer, i would be very happy if you could look at my code ^^ –